# Empty storage bucket at Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to do the file upload using firebase storage, as i read from the docs i need a reference so i can control things, so i did this:

```
FirebaseStorage storage;    
StorageReference storageRef;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_settings);
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com>");
}

public void editPhoto(View view){
    // Create a reference to "mountains.jpg"
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    i.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(i,GALLERY_IMG);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // Check which request we're responding to
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_IMG  && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        StorageReference filePath = storageRef.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        filePath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(UserSettings.this, "Upload Done",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
           @Override
           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

           }
        });
    }
}
```

it says that this line:          `storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com>");`

has the null point expection, what is going on?, what do i need extra to put this on work?

Answer (score 0):

`storage` is null because you have not instantiate it. Before doing anything with Firebase Storage you need to create an instance of it:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
```

Add previous line before `getReferenceFromUrl` call in your `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_settings);
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://<friendlymanager-3b7a2.appspot.com>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If someone else is facing this issue after following the tutorials.
Check that the `FirebaseStorage` instance is instantiated as below

```
let storage = Storage.storage()
```

and NOT `let storage = Storage()`

Spent hours figuring out what was wrong.

:/